# Method for comparing 2 3-dimensional networks (igraphs in R)

Tags: r, networks, igraph

I'm looking for a way to compare 2 (or more) igraph objects in R. These are trajectories in 3-dim which are a network of nodes and edges but are not necessarily the same number of either, just that they have a corresponding coordinate in 3-dim.

I think something like Procrustes could work nicely but requires an equal number of points, and so I'd need a pre-step like iterative closest point (ICP) to find correspondences between the network.

I fear I have gone down the rabbit hole trying to fit a solution to Procrustes (and have yet to get a sensible answer from ICP so far), and thought I'd reach out to the smart people in this community and see if there's a technique I'm missing. This is a new area for me so grateful for any advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a *basis* for comparison.  Otherwise, this question is no different than, say, asking for a way to compare two fruits or two animals or two systems of government: the possible answers are endless.